# How to set datagridview's rows/columns width to the datagridview's width?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

Excuse me, a quick question:

I am using this routine to display a list of strings into a datagridview:

```
List<string> MyDataSource = MyList.Select(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)).ToList();

AllVideosGrid.DataSource = MyDataSource.ConvertAll(x => new { Value = x });
```

Designer generated code:

```
// MyGrid
// 
this.AllVideosGrid.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.AllVideosGrid.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(33, 185);
this.AllVideosGrid.Name = "AllVideosGrid";
this.AllVideosGrid.RowTemplate.Height = 24;
this.AllVideosGrid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(319, 498);
this.AllVideosGrid.TabIndex = 32;
```

And it gets displayed like this:

[image]

I would like rows to be resized to the datagridview size that I set initially in my designer. How can I do that?

Comment: what is the designer generated code?

Comment: @kennyzx oh, right,. edited ! Thanks

Comment: Try AutoSizeColumnsMode to Fill

Comment: @kennyzx Worked ! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for horizontal strecth use this:

```
this.AllVideosGrid.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

For vertical I think that's not possible, eventually you can set the height for each row

Comment: As @kennyzx 's comment, [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547196/how-to-set-datagridviews-rows-size-to-the-datagridviews-size#comment74146793_43547196) works too ! Thanks